# xamarin, Gson 1.7.1 getting Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, android, gson

I'm using xamarin 8.0 with visual studio 2017 community edition.  The project also uses google GSon 1.7.1

I'm getting `Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>`
when this instanciating the `JSon class: Gson gson = new Gson();`

`This error in stops in the fallowing line (at Com.Google.Gson.GsonBuilder):
public unsafe global::Com.Google.Gson.GsonBuilder ExcludeFieldsWithModifiers (params  int[] p0)
        {
            if (id_excludeFieldsWithModifiers_arrayI == IntPtr.Zero)
                id_excludeFieldsWithModifiers_arrayI = JNIEnv.GetMethodID (class_ref, "excludeFieldsWithModifiers", "([I)Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;");
            IntPtr native_p0 = JNIEnv.NewArray (p0);
            try {
                JValue* __args = stackalloc JValue [1];
                __args [0] = new JValue (native_p0);
                global::Com.Google.Gson.GsonBuilder __ret = global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Google.Gson.GsonBuilder> (JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (((global::Java.Lang.Object) this).Handle, id_excludeFieldsWithModifiers_arrayI, __args), JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
                return __ret;
            } finally {
                if (p0 != null) {
                    JNIEnv.CopyArray (native_p0, p0);
                    JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef (native_p0);
                }
            }
        }`

Please help, I have searched every where and no one seems to have this problem.

Thank you !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and especially https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Gson 1.7.1 is much too old, have you tried the latest version of Gson?

Comment: Yes, but any way I need to use that version, because the paysafe sdk uses it it too... Ad that is the reason this is used in the first place.